# Windows Azure Worker Role and SVG

Tags: c#, iis, graphics, azure, svg

I want to use a worker role to serve up images and various pieces of content in Windows Azure. One of my requirements is to serve up an SVG as a PNG file of the requested size. These PNGs will be cached to ensure maximum performance in the long run but I do need these SVGs to be rendered in memory and as quickly as possible.

What is the best solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SVG Rendering](http://svg.codeplex.com/) Engine open source project. It seems to both generated SVGs and generate other files from SVGs.